Is it possible to create a git bundle of a revision range with minimal prerequisites that can be applied to a shallow clone?
The documentation for git-bundle states the following about git bundles of revision ranges:

A revision range such as old..new will produce a bundle file that will require the revision old (and any objects reachable from it) to exist for the bundle to be "unbundle"-able:

Unfortunately, when I create a bundle of a revision range using git bundle create foo.bundle <old>..<new> in a large monorepo, I discovered that list of explicit prerequisites included many more commits in addition to the revision <old>.
Furthermore, I noticed that the other listed revisions were all ancestors of <old>.
The existence of these prerequisites means that I cannot unbundle successfully into a shallow clone which did not include the earlier prerequisites:
git clone --depth=20 <my_git_repo>
cd my_git_repo

git bundle unbundle foo.bundle
error: Repository lacks these prerequisite commits:
error: e30224501986e66cf178f68945edeab9d7d100d2
error: e3f7879425a839c0dca9b483f9593eb7e293d090
error: 7ccbcfc0f56a961f2e1edb8102d555fb795e4d14


As an experiment, I tried manually removing these extra prerequisites from the bundle file (leaving only the <old> revision and unbundling:
git bundle unbundle  ../../../removed_prerequisites_foo.bundle
Unbundling objects: 100% (3256/3256), 4.49 MiB | 69.60 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:  99% (1423/1426), completed with 727 local objects.
fatal: pack has 3 unresolved deltas
error: index-pack died


This error implies that the bundle includes objects that are stored as deltas, and that is why there are explicit dependencies on commits that are earlier than <old>.
Is there a way to force git bundle to pack full objects that depend only on <old>?
I have checked the git-bundle documentation and found the following statement suggests it might not be possible with git bundle command, but I am curious about whether I can use lower-level commands or magic config options to achieve the effect of getting bundle with only <old> as a prerequisite, so that it can be unbundled in a shallow clone.

Bundles created using revision exclusions are "thin packs" created
using the --thin option to git-pack-objects, and unbundled using
the --fix-thin option to git-index-pack.
There is no option to create a "thick pack" when using revision
exclusions, and users should not be concerned about the difference. By
using "thin packs", bundles created using exclusions are smaller in
size. That they’re "thin" under the hood is merely noted here as a
curiosity, and as a reference to other documentation.


My original answer was a useful stepping stone but did not solve the full problem.

It can correctly eliminate logical prerequisites resulting from delta compression
It cannot eliminate prerequisites resulting from parent relationships that arise from merging in a commit that is based on an ancestor of <old>.

The new approach that I ended up using to create the bundle:

Disable delta compression temporarily: git config set core.bigFileThreshold 1
Use git rev-list --boundary to identify the commits that would be in the bundle as well as the commits that would be in the prerequisites.
Identify the set of commits that are in the shallow clone.
Iterate over all the commits that would be in the bundle:
a) If the commit has a parent in the prerequisites list that is NOT in the shallow clone, use git replace --graft <commit_sha> [remaining_parents] to create a replacement ref and effectively "truncate" the history.
Create a bundle that includes all the replacement refs. This bundle will not have any prerequisites that are not in the shallow clone.

I then used the followed method to unbundle, because git fetch <bundle> does not respect replacement refs:

git bundle unbundle <bundle>
git bundle list-heads  <bundle> | while read -r sha ref; do git update-ref $ref $sha; done


After a bunch of experimentation, I was able to cobble together a hacky approach that seems to produce a thick pack:

Disable delta compression temporarily: git config set core.bigFileThreshold 1
Create the bundle: git bundle create no_delta.bundle <old>..<new>.
Manually remove the revisions that are ancestors of <old> using a script:

#!/bin/bash
bundle_file="$1"
old_sha="$2"

prerequisites="$(strings "$bundle_file" | grep -o -E  '^-([0-9a-f]){40}')"
ex_cmds=""
while read -r prereq; do
  prereq="${prereq:1}"
  if [[ "$prereq" = "$old_sha" ]]; then
   continue
  fi

  if git merge-base --is-ancestor ${prereq} ${old_sha}; then
    ex_cmds+="g/-${prereq}/d"$'\n'
  else
    echo "Preserve ${prereq}"
  fi
done <<<"$prerequisites"
ex_cmds+=$'wq'
echo "${ex_cmds}"
echo "${ex_cmds}" | ex -b "$bundle_file"



Restore delta compression: git config unset core.bigFileThreshold


While this solution works, it is hacky and possibly brittle if the format of the bundle file changes.
I am still interested in more git-native approaches that do not require manual edits to bundle files if others have them.

Boy, this feels really hacky indeed. In your application, do you have the option to shallowly fetch those additional commits before unbundling? (git fetch --depth=1 <sha> does appear to shallowly fetch just commit <sha>). The end result would still minimize how much data has to be transferred to apply the bundle, which I figure is likely what you're trying to accomplish. (But yes, I'm aware, this is not answering your question as asked.)

This is an interesting idea! I'm not sure because I don't own the system that is currently experiencing this problem (the system falls back to creating
a snapshot of a dedicated shallow clone for each commit instead of a bundle whenever prerequisites are not met, which is almost every time), but I can suggest this idea to the owners.

I'm curious to know whether this idea went anywhere...

@joanis It turns out that neither this hacky solution and your suggestion are both insufficient to produce a bundle that can be consistently unpacked and lead to a coherent repository. I'll write a new answer that describes what we ended up doing.
